# pptx-python - Powerpoint always opens on master slide page

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I have an app that creates powerpoints. Everything goes well except that every time I want to open one of these powerpoints it opens it in the slide master view. This isn't necessarily a problem per se, but just annoying since I open a lot of these powerpoint files. Has anyone else encountered this? Any idea what this is due to?

This happens on both mac and windows.

I create a presentation from a template, generate the slides and then save it more or less like this:

```
self.prs = Presentation(
            self.template_path)
for c, slide in enumerate(self.data):
    self.generate_slide(slide)
self.prs.save(save_location)
```

Comment: Could it be a problem with the template? Have you tried your code with a different template or no template?

Comment: @Ludo: can you guide as to how to make use of template to create a new pptx entirely? Right now i am able to create a ppt from blank presentation but not from existing presentation.

Comment: @RSM just instantiate your presentation with a filename for eg `prs = Presentation('existing-prs-file.pptx')` . If that doesn't work ask a new question and I or someone else can answer it.

Comment: @Ludo: I have asked this question here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59561983/6389099

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue before, it was because the template slide was saved in the slide master view same as what Johnathon said.