# Python-PPTX: KeyError: 'no placeholder on this slide with idx == 1'

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am trying to use an existing powerpoint presentation as a template and then insert my slides in the same.

I am not concerned about the existing slides in the presentation and i would like to delete them (I haven't planned how yet), but i am more focused that the new slides created will have the same font and color scheme as the existing ones.

Below is my code:

```
prs = Presentation('UNTITLED.pptx')
slide_master = prs.slide_master

def add_slide(prs, layout, title, data1, data2):
    """Return slide newly added to `prs` using `layout` and having `title`."""
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(layout)
    slide.shapes.title.text = title
    slide.placeholders[1].text = data1
    slide.placeholders[2].text = data2
    return slide


var1 = "Secondary header for Slide1 !!!"

#Defination to create the new slide with layout and title:
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[3]
slide1 = add_slide(prs, title_slide_layout, "Summary Table", "This is the text for slide 1", var1)
```

This works properly when i do not use a templete but when i do, it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/test.py", line 47, in <module>
    slide1 = add_slide(prs, title_slide_layout, "Summary Table", "This is the text for slide 1", var1)
  File "C:/Users/test.py", line 35, in add_slide
    slide.placeholders[1].text = data1
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pptx\shapes\shapetree.py", line 730, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError("no placeholder on this slide with idx == %d" % idx)
KeyError: 'no placeholder on this slide with idx == 1'
```

Any help on the error is appreciated.

Comment: On the subsidiary question of how to delete existing slides, here's what I did: I base my presentation on a .pptm (PowerPoint with Macros) file. The first slide has a button with a VBA macro on it. This macro deletes this first slide and saves the resulting presentation as a .pptx file. You could do something similar.

Answer (score 2):

This error means you've asked for a placeholder that does not exist on that slide.

Placeholder access is a little tricky, in that a placeholder is identified by its "key", not by its position in the (z-order) sequence of placeholders on the slide. This key is called "idx" (name chosen by Microsoft), which perhaps makes it more potentially confusing.

I recommend you read this page of the documentation to familiarize yourself with the details: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/placeholders-using.html

The following code is an example of how you can query a slide for the keys (idxs) and names of the placeholders it contains, which will give you a valid set of choices:

```
>>> prs = Presentation()
>>> slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[8])
>>> for shape in slide.placeholders:
...     print('%d %s' % (shape.placeholder_format.idx, shape.name))
...
0  Title 1
1  Picture Placeholder 2
2  Text Placeholder 3
```

Comment: See the other answer. I think for whatever reason (broken template?) this code returns all `idx` values as `0` in my case. Thus, there is no possibility to access `slide.placeholders[1]` because it doesn't exist despite other placeholders existing. In other words, my output is just like yours, but replace your leftmost "column" with all `0` values.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem where I knew there were three placeholders on my slide but I was only able to edit the first one (index = 0). I got the same error when I tried to edit the others (e.g. index = 1)

Example below is how I got around it:

```
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(layout)
a, b, c = slide.placeholders
a.text = 'placeholder text 1'
b.text = 'placeholder text 2'
c.text = 'placeholder text 3'
```

Comment: This is fantastic. I think the problem is that compared to the answer from @scanny, something is wrong with the `idx` of the placeholders. Mine are *all* `0` when I run the [sample code](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/placeholders-using.html) printing `idx` and `name` for a slide. This variable expansion is a great workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue, no matter what I did the placeholders which I created in my Slide Master View did not want to show up( in my case only one placeholder was showing up).

I kept playing around with it and it turns out that when you create a slide from the corresponding slide master template, it will only capture the placeholders that slide master has in that moment. If you change the slide master ph(s)(a.k.a placeholders), it will not reflect in your normal view. Therefore, if you want the ph(s) to show up from your slide master in your normal slides, you have to create the slide from the slide master slide.

As a test, create a new slide from the desired slide master but make sure that the desired slide master has the ph(s). Then read that slides placeholders using below code :

```html
new_slide_index = "place the index of new slide here"
slide = prs.slides[new_slide_index]
list_ph_names = [shape.name for shape in slide.placeholders]
```